# Make a tabbed Workbook of Spreadsheets with TabView (and TableView)

Tags: list-manipulation, spreadsheets

I'd like to display a 3D table as a tabbed group of 2D tables. As a bonus incorporate TableView to enable editing.

[image]

Here is my attempt:
[image]

Comment: So, what is the question? How is `TabView[Table[TableForm@Table[{i, j}, {j, 4}], {i, 3}]]` different than what you intend?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the question but perhaps this approximates what you seek:

```
TabView[Table[
  TableForm@Table[{i, Style[Framed[j], Red]}, {j, 4}], {i, 3}]]
```

Which produces:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using your test data,

```
tables = Table[{i, j}, {i, 3}, {j, 4}, {2}]
```

we would need to tell TableView what the type is, because otherwise it won't know how to handle the data that is deeper that 2D.

```
TableView /@ tables (*just returns unevaluated*)
TableView[#, Expression] & /@ tables (*gives two "spreadsheets" *)
```

Then we can wrap with the TabView

```
TabView[TableView[#, Expression] & /@ tables]
```

Note, you hinted at editing, and so you may end up needing variables and Dynamic in there somewhere to persist edits to the variables.